# How to render template by respective if condition in thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my project i have multiple template but i want to code it within one html page and render it by giving some condition.Each template is in div tag. But i am not able to render one template by providing one condition and second by providing second condition.

```
 hello.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
<title>State 1</title>
</head>

<div th:fragment="contentA">
<body>

<form method="post">

    <label><b>Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" v-
 model="value1"/>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>


    <label><b>Date of Birth</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Birth date" name="dob" v-
    model="value2"/>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <label><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" v-
    model="value3"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" v-model="value4"/> 
    Remember me
    <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms and 
   Privacy</a>.</p>

    <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="button"  class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="submitbtn">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  </body>
  </div>

<div th:fragment="contentB"> // another template
<body>
<h1 th:text="${messages}"></h1>
</body>
 </div>
</html>
```

This is my another html page for rendering by giving condition :

```
 helloform.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Hello, Ola CVS!!! </title>
</head>
<body>

<div th:if="${messages.checkstatus == 0}"
 th:replace="hello :: contentA"/>


<div th:if="${messages.checkstatus == 1}"
 th:replace="hello :: contentB" />

</body>
</html>
```

Please find my java code also to render by adding value into Model model:

```
   protected Response getUI(SMEvent event,Model model) {

  if(checkstate==1 && checkstatus==0)
    {

        model.addAttribute("messages.checkstatus" , 0);
        System.out.println("Entering to get the page for state 1 and 
        status 0"+ model);
        return Response.ok().entity("helloform").build();
    }

    if(checkstate==1 && checkstatus==1)
    {
        if(checkstate==1)
        {

           model.addAttribute("messages.checkstatus" , 1);

            System.out.println("Entering to get the page of state 1 and 
          status 1" + model);
            return Response.ok().entity("helloform").build();
        }

      }
   }
```

Comment: if you want to render in a html template, use ModelAndView objects with the name of your template, but seems you are returnning a different kind of object

Comment: Thanks for response!!! but my return type is response. and as i think the issue is not with the model but it is with "  <div th:if="${messages.checkstatus == 0}"
 th:replace="hello :: contentA"/>


<div th:if="${messages.checkstatus == 1}"
 th:replace="hello :: contentB" />"

Comment: try this, print the value of checkStatus, <h1 th:text="${messages.cehckStatus}"></h1> and we can verify if the value is correct. I am afraid your model is not going to the view

Comment: If i change messages.cehckStatus to messages then it is returning the correct value which i want :
and the i made changes like :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Hello, Ola CVS!!! </title>
</head>
<body>

<!--<h1 th:text="${messages}"/>-->

<div th:if="${messages == 0}"
     th:replace="hello :: contentA"/>


<div th:if="${messages == 1}"
     th:replace="hello :: contentB" />

</body>
</html>

and it is going into other html page i.e hello.html but it is executing both div every time

Comment: But i want if messages return 0 then <div th:fragment="contentA"> should execute and if messages return 1 then <div th:fragment="contentB"> should execute

Answer (score 2):

th:replace happens before th:if, according to [thymeleaf attribute precedence](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#attribute-precedence).  You just need to move the th:if into a tag above the replace.  Something like this:

```
<th:block th:if="${messages.checkstatus == 0}">
  <div th:replace="hello :: contentA" />
</th:block>

<th:block th:if="${messages.checkstatus == 1}">
  <div th:replace="hello :: contentB" />
</th:block>
```

Answer (score 0):

Work for me.

I using the backend service to process color code

```
use >>> th:styleappend

Status :

<span style="font-size: 11px;"
   th:styleappend="${'color:' + projectStatusColor + ';'}"
   th:text="${projectStatusName}"></span>
```

because the values in the CSS property **style** cannot be parsed.

but it works for me. ^__^